# Mysql select/join?

Tags: php, mysql

Earlier I was taught how to select and concat in a query *(Used that to add some text to some image urls)*.

However, I am quite stumped now. The next thing I need to tackle is "grabbing" each individual cards url. Unfortunately the url is not stored in the database, instead it is made up by pulling the corresponding `category`, `sub category`, and then the cards `name`.

I know to use

```
select name from cards
```

but then after that I am pretty much lost.
There are 3 main tables I have narrowed it down to.

1. Card_categories contains `category_id_card_id`, `card_category_id`.
2. Categories contain `category_id`, `name`.
3. Cards contains `card_id` and other card related information.

I do know the url structure needs to be `www.amyadele.com/name(category)/sub category/name` (from cards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps reading up on the JOIN examples would help you: http://mysqljoin.com/joins/inner-join-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

```
select
  concat('www.amydale.com/', mc.name, '/', sc.name, '/', c.name) as url
from
  cards c
  inner join subcategory sc on sc.subcategoryid = c.subcategoryid
  inner join category mc on mc.categoryid = sc.categoryid
```

Answer (score 0):

yes - read up on JOINS, then look up 'CONCATENATION'

you can 'grab' all the values, and append them to each other as one single string result.

Comment: Yeah, I am just confused of what needs to be joined together in this case.